# Light Box Picture Library

Tags: 2010, picture-library

I've looked at the ootb picture library and seems dated. I want to utilise something like a light box to provide a better UI, perhaps with slideshow.

[The one here is good but its for 2007](http://blog.drisgill.com/2008/10/new-codeplex-project-lytebox-for.html)

It's utilising: [LyteBox](http://lytebox.com)

Has anyone already created something similiar using a Picture Library  and can share thoughts ?

Comment: Orange Juice: Please tag the SharePoint version.

Comment: yeah, that slide show sucks. I'll be working on the same thing tonight except using prettyPhoto if you'd like to try that...http://blog.mikehacker.net/2009/06/10/sharepoint-photo-gallery-using-jquery/

Comment: Hi Thanks for this :)  I've noticed the code is using webservices with AJAX. I was wondering if this could be also accomplished using CSOM(javascript) and AJAX, or does CSOM not support AJAX?